# React-Google-Maps component hiding other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I am trying to have a react-google-map component appear on my website, along with my navbar and footer componenets. However, the map makes everything disappear on my page. How do I get the map to appear in my  only.

I originally had the displayMap() function and WrappedMap exported with one component, but I had an issue with map re-rendering on markers being closed.

```
//Map.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'react-google-maps';
import * as schools from '../data/schools.json';

function Display() {
    const [selectedSchool, setSelectedSchool] = useState(null)

    function displayMap() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <GoogleMap defaultZoom={3} defaultCenter={{ lat: 50, lng: -50 }}
                </GoogleMap>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

const Map = (props) => {
    const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Display));

    return (
        <WrappedMap
            googleMapURL=mapsURL
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />} />
    );
};

export default Map;
```

```
//Education.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Map from '../components/Map';
import ContactFooter from '../components/ContactFooter';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const Education = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <main className="education">
                {/* <Map /> */}
            </main>
            <footer>
                <ContactFooter />
            </footer>
        </>
    );
};

export default Education;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

needed to delete the line function displayMap() and only use display()